# Importing typescript store into sveltecomponent

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I have this typescript store, with a few classes initiated and passed through.

Under `src/stores/gamestore.ts`

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

import ChessGame from '$lib/classes/Chess/ChessGame';
import ChessBoard from '$lib/classes/Chess/ChessBoard';
import { AbstractPlayer } from '$lib/classes/BoardGame/Player';
import { PieceColor } from '$lib/classes/BoardGame/Piece';
import { AbstractGameScore } from '$lib/classes/BoardGame/GameScore';

// ... instantiate your classes
const board = new ChessBoard();
const p1 = new AbstractPlayer('test', PieceColor.White);
const p2 = new AbstractPlayer('test', PieceColor.Black);
const score = new AbstractGameScore();
const chessGame = new ChessGame(board, [p1, p2], score);

export default writable({
    game: chessGame,
    board: chessGame.board,
    players: chessGame.players,
    score: chessGame.score,
    currentPlayer: chessGame.currentPlayer,
    winner: chessGame.winner
});
```

And under a random sveltecomponent I try to import this file, I get the error

```
Svelte: File
s:/Desktop/.../src/stores/gameStore.ts
is not a module.
```

```
<script lang="ts">
    import ChessGame from '$lib/classes/Chess/ChessGame';
    import gameStore from '$stores/gameStore';

    console.log('game', gameStore);
</script>

<div />
```

I can import a regular typescript class as shown in the script tag, the ChessGame import directly will work, but I want to try and make it persistent in memory for ease of development.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"],
            "$lib":["./src/lib"],
            "$lib/*":["./src/lib/*"],
            "$stores/*": ["./src/stores/*"]
        }
    },

    // Path aliases are handled by https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias
    //
    // If you want to overwrite includes/excludes, make sure to copy over the relevant includes/excludes
    // from the referenced tsconfig.json - TypeScript does not merge them in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the TS config paths, does not mean the build system will be able to resolve them. It even tells you right there in the config:

> Path aliases are handled by https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias

Using the [`alias` config](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias) will auto-generate TS-config paths in the generated `.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json` and pass them on to Vite.